# the selection changed is not rise when I select item in the constructor

Tags: c#-4.0, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a view and a viewModel. In my constructor of my viewModel I have this code:

```
Dgd01.Add(myElement);
Dgd01SelectedIndex = 0;
```

I am using MVVMLight to implement the selectionChanged event of my dataGrid, but the event is not rised.

I have a button to clean the selection, then I select the element in the dataGrid and the selection event is rised.

I guess that the problem is that I am doing the selection in the constructor, but I don't know if this is the real reason of the problem and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Try to raise selecteionChanged event on windowLoaded event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the view model is not associated with the view when the constructor is executed.

Why can't you try the below method

- You can have a private method which does the actual task when selectionChanged event fires.

void DoOperationOnSelection(int selectedIndex / object selectedItem)
{
}

- So the eventHandler may call this method with selectedIndex/item
- Call that method explicitly from the constructor as follows

Dgd01.Add(myElement);

DoOperationOnSelection(0);